# I am trying to hide and show an element based on states but it could not worked?

Tags: reactjs, show-hide

the problem is that I  am trying to hide and show elements based on states with conditional rendring but it would not worked .

I have set the state of element and pass the method in onmouseover and onmouse leave event first time it worked for one element when I repeat the  same process for second element it would not worked.

```
  constructor(props)
  {

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      show: false,
      opticare: false
    }

    this.handleSwitch = this.handleSwitch.bind(this)
    this.leave = this.leave.bind(this)
    this.handleOpti = this.handleOpti.bind(this)
    this.handleCare = this.handleCare.bind(this)
  }

  handleSwitch = () => {
    this.setState({
      show: !this.state.switch

    })
  }
  leave = () => {

    this.setState({
      show: this.state.switch

    })

  }
  handleOpti = () => {
    this.setState({
      opticare: !this.state.opticare
    })
  }
  handleCare = () => {
    this.setState({
      opticare: this.state.opticare
    })
  }

  render()
  {
    let className = 'reading-friends'
    if (this.state.show) {
      className = 'reading-friends visible'
    } else if (!this.state.show) {
      className = 'reading-friends invisible'
    }

    let addClass = 'opti-care'
    if (this.state.opticare) {
      addClass = 'opti-care visible'
    } else if (!this.state.opticare) {
      addClass = 'opti-care invisible'
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div className="row ">
            <div className="row ">
              <div className={className} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <h1 className="heading" style={{
                  fontSize: '50px',
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  marginTop: '140px',
                  marginBottom: '200px',
                  fontFamily: 'catamaran,sans-serif'
                }}>Reading Friends</h1>
                <p className="parah">Reading Friends is designed to engage young children by
                  promoting interactive learning through games, puzzles,<br/>
                  and music. Appealing to children's instinctual inquisitiveness,
                  Reading Friends brings education to life with exciting graphics,<br/>
                  spirited sound and creative activities
                  that help them learn to read, while entertaining them through play.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }} className={addClass}>
              <h1 style={{
                fontSize: '50px',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                marginBottom: '200px',
                fontFamily: 'catamaran,sans-serif'
              }}>Opticare Solution</h1>
              <p>OptiCare Solution is a complete mini ERP for opticians and optometrists.<br/>
                We are the first to bring such an extensive solution in the field of Optometry,<br></br>
                providing features that are robust and easy to use.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row"></div>
        </div>
        <div style={{ marginTop: '270px' }} className="row ">

          <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center">

            <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.planetreading.readingfriends">
              <img onMouseOut={this.leave} onMouseOver={this.handleSwitch}
                   src="http://newstate.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/work-reading-friends-colored.png"
                   alt="" class="we-do-img we-work-img img-responsive grayscale"/>
            </a>

          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img onMouseOut={this.handleCare} onMouseOver={this.handleOpti}
                 src="http://newstate.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/work-opticare-colored.png"
                 alt="" class="we-do-img we-work-img img-responsive grayscale"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: `show: !this.state.switch` may be `show: !this.state.show` ?

Comment: `switch` property in `state` is not defined anywhere

Comment: this one is working the second one (opticare is not working)

Comment: your `handleCare` do nothing. May be you want to use `handleOpti` for both `onMouseOut` and `onMouseOver`?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create two separate functions for both `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`. You can use a single function for both event-listeners.

Just create two functions, one for each state-value you want to toggle. In the code below, we'll use `handleSwitch` and `handleOpti`.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-cookies-4mcwt

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      opticare: false
    };

  }

  handleSwitch = () => {
    this.setState({
      show: !this.state.show
    });
  };

  handleOpti = () => {
    this.setState({
      opticare: !this.state.opticare
    });
  };

  render() {
    let className = "reading-friends";
    if (this.state.show) {
      className = "reading-friends visible";
    } else if (!this.state.show) {
      className = "reading-friends invisible";
    }

    let addClass = "opti-care";
    if (this.state.opticare) {
      addClass = "opti-care visible";
    } else if (!this.state.opticare) {
      addClass = "opti-care invisible";
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div className="row ">
            <div className="row ">
              <div className={className} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <h1
                  className="heading"
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "50px",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    marginTop: "140px",
                    marginBottom: "200px",
                    fontFamily: "catamaran,sans-serif"
                  }}
                >
                  Reading Friends
                </h1>
                <p className="parah">
                  Reading Friends is designed to engage young children by
                  promoting interactive learning through games, puzzles,
                  <br />
                  and music. Appealing to children's instinctual
                  inquisitiveness, Reading Friends brings education to life with
                  exciting graphics,
                  <br />
                  spirited sound and creative activities that help them learn to
                  read, while entertaining them through play.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }} className={addClass}>
              <h1
                style={{
                  fontSize: "50px",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  marginBottom: "200px",
                  fontFamily: "catamaran,sans-serif"
                }}
              >
                Opticare Solution
              </h1>
              <p>
                OptiCare Solution is a complete mini ERP for opticians and
                optometrists.
                <br />
                We are the first to bring such an extensive solution in the
                field of Optometry,
                <br />
                providing features that are robust and easy to use.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row" />
        </div>
        <div style={{ marginTop: "270px" }} className="row ">
          <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.planetreading.readingfriends">
              <img
                onMouseOut={this.handleSwitch}
                onMouseOver={this.handleSwitch}
                src="http://newstate.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/work-reading-friends-colored.png"
                alt=""
                class="we-do-img we-work-img img-responsive grayscale"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img
              onMouseOut={this.handleOpti}
              onMouseOver={this.handleOpti}
              src="http://newstate.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/work-opticare-colored.png"
              alt=""
              class="we-do-img we-work-img img-responsive grayscale"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `leave` and `handleSwitch` function, you are using  `switch` property of the state instead of show property. 
Also, there is no need to use bind if you are using arrow functions.